# Kendo grid and Jquery is not working on Viiew

Tags: jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui

I need a progress bar(Jquery ui ) in my view page .The page also contains a kendo Grid..

So  I added these files    (jquery-ui.css,jquery-.js,jquery-ui.js) but adding jquery.js
Showing error Object Object has no method kendo grid

Using Updated version of Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably included jQuery twice. The second instance will wipe out any jQuery plugins (e.g. Kendo) which were previously registered. You should include only one instance of jQuery in your page.